# How to add zeros onto a number

Tags: php

I have a number that is being returned from my database and I'd like to have trailing zeros after the decimal place. I've tried round but that doesn't work.

$18.0 should be $18.00. What function would I use for this?

Comment: Is your number `'$18.0'` or just `18.0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function for that.

Or `sprintf` like this:

```
$money1 = 68.75;
$money2 = 54.35;
$money = $money1 + $money2;

// echo $money will output "123.1";

$formatted = sprintf("%01.2f", $money); // << this does the trick!

// echo $formatted will output "123.10"
```

Comment: Thanks Sarfraz, I'll credit you for the answer after the 5 minute time constraint lapses.

Comment: Yeppers... Worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

printf\sprintf depending on your db it may be easier to use it than php

Answer (score 1):

Try money_format():

```
$number = 1234.56;

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
```

Complete information on money_format is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation on [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

```
sprintf("%.2f",$var)
```